# How to perform two different functions for a single uibutton action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton and a action to it.Now i need to perform some task when user clicks the button for the first time and another set of statements when user clicks for the second time.How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what are you asking....please asking question with full description.

Comment: What should happen if user clicks third time?

Answer (score 4):

Not understand what's your issue but according to question title you crate two Method that you want to perform alternate in single button Action click event for example:-

```
-(void)MethodFirst
{
// your code
}

-(void)Methodsecond
{
// your code
}

-(IBAction)Yourbuttonclick:(UIButton *)sender
{
   sender.selected=!sender.selected;
   if (sender.selected)
   {
       [self MethodFirst];
   }
   else
   {
      [self Methodsecond];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define a `static int counter = 0` in your function, and increment the counter each time the button is pressed eg, `counter++;` then have an if statement

```
if(counter == 0){
//do first set of instructions
}
else {
//do second set
}
```

Comment: use static variable is not good in this case.It'll make more variable and use more memory. It will need to release, if not it will raise up to a very big value every time when user click the button. the answer of @Nitin Gohel is good one.

Comment: that isnt how static variables work, also the int data type is a primitive and therefore does not need to be released. it isnt the best solution but its the fastest/easiest for such a simple problem

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the below one is your action. Take a bool variable globally say BOOL isalreadyClicked; and set it as NO.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
if(isalreadyClicked)
{
 /// your work here

 isalreadyClicked=NO;
}
else
{
 /// your work here
 isalreadyClicked=YES;   
}
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

give a tag to button for firsttime and check tag in action method
egg
button.tag = 100; //firsttime

```
-(void)buttonaction:(UIButton*)sender{
if(sender.tag == 100){
// do something for first time
sender.tag = 200;
}
else if(sender.tag == 200) { //second time
// do something for second time
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a BOOL value.

In your .m:

```
-(IBAction)methodButton{

    self.flag = !self.flag;

    if (self.flag == YES){
       //Here do your first task


    }

    if (self.flag == NO){
       //Here do your second task
    }

}
```